# Webtorrent - Can I seed only a small part of a file?

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, webtorrent

I wanted to know if it is possible to seed only a part of a file from one client ? I want to create a volunteer computation webcl cluster, but for the computations to start, I need to give them a cache (16 - 32 mb). The thing is that this cache could be computed by the clients . So my question is , can I compute small parts of this cache, and seed these parts as "piece number x of cache" and of course in the same time download all the other parts I don't have ? Like this , the whole file will be seeded, but no one will have it fully on their computer, and each time a client downloads a brand new computed part, it starts seeding this part too ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. WebTorrent follows BitTorrent spec. A torrent contains files.

You can however, download & seed a small part of the full torrent, which might work for you.

You'd need to generate torrent of the full file and create a seeder that downloads and seed the part that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem was that I needed to be able to seed from parts only, but I guess It couldn't work so I changed my method now !